# Enabling auto-completion in git bash on windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I would like to be able to type

```
git checkout <start-of-branch-name>
```

...and then hit tab and have the branch name autocomplete for me. How can I enable this?

Comment: For me, this just works in git bash. If you're on Windows, I'd recommend using Powershell with posh-git.

Comment: That comment ^ is a better answer since /etc/ dones't exist on windows and you're not going to have that bash file without first curling it

Comment: The link above (code-worrier.com) does not exist any longer (November 2018)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the problem could be as simple as not being in a git-controlled path. Check by issuing the `git status` command and see if you get an error.

If you are in a git path, try to source the `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` file and try the tab completion again. If this works, do the following:

1. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

`. /etc/bash_completion.d/git`

2. Log out.
3. Open a new mintty session (you are using mintty, right? Tab completion might not work from "cmd" prompt or Powershell.)
4. Type `git` followed by a space, then hit the Tab key twice to test. You should get a list of the git subcommands.

Tab completion on the branch name should now work for you. Eg. `git branch ma <TAB>` should complete as `git branch master`.

Comment: You leave out some important details. Assuming you're using git-bash, you have to `mkdir -p /etc/bash_completion.d/git` right? And you have to get the git autocompletion directory/script from somewhere....

Comment: This is a comporehensive answer to this question, albeit for `ssh`, git works analogously: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp

Comment: for me the path with cygwin was `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` instead of `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`

Comment: With `git-bash` the path for me was `/mingw64/share/git/completion/` which maps to `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\completion`

Comment: thanks @TimAbell, that is the correct directory on Windows! I wonder how I add completion for other things in git-bash on windows

Comment: instruction for windows in not clear at all. Where is the `~/.bashrc` file on windows please ? Instead of `. /etc/bash_completion.d/git` what to put if in the file if we are on windows?

Comment: @rfay, I did not have to do the mkdir that you had to do. But, yes, if it's not in your session then you would have to create it.

Comment: @stic-lab, my answer above assumes you are in a `mintty` session with the Linux environment already in place. The ~/.bashrc file is in your home directory. The /etc/bash_completion.d exists in your session root. etc. If you are in a Powershell or DOS prompt, all bets are off. :shrug

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Windows 11.

```
C\:/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-completion.bash
```